# check multiple instance availabiliy with mutiple mutex?

Tags: c#

I am run two tasks parallel one another one, here i am running a task with start form his `program.cs` and when it goes to `form.cs` there i am start a new application of another exe within it.

I am using mutex for checking instance of it. I am using mutex in `program.cs` and add another mutex for check another exe instance of it, but it show already ruuning.. i will try explain with code..

in program .cs of first application

```
  static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{sdfssdfdsf-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");

 Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "asa", out ok);
            if (!ok)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Another Instance Is Already running of This Application", "Cyber Security", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("System is exiting.", "Systems");
                    Application.ExitThread();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

in Form.cs

```
 static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{asdasd-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-asfsadf}");

 Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "ASDA", out ok);
                if (!ok)
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Another Instance Is Already running of This Application", "log", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("System is exiting.", "Log");
                        Application.ExitThread();
                        return;
                    }
                }


//but this show thee error the second instance is already ruunning?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "asa", out ok);
 Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "ASDA", out ok);
```

They both need the same name

```
 Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "ASDA", out ok);
```

should be

```
 Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "asa", out ok);
                                              ^-------------------Change
```

Comment: in this the name of all the same,

Comment: the unique of all keys different but this is not running please check my code pls i have change the name of it due to security reason

Comment: What is the problem you are having?